# How can I solve "Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::create()" in the Maatwebsite excel on laravel?

Tags: excel, laravel, export-to-excel, laravel-5.6

I using laravel 5.6 and Maatwebsite version 3

From this tutorial https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel

I try like this :

```
public function exportToExcel(Request $request)
{
    $header_item[] = array('Item Number', 'Description', 'Remaining Quantity', 'Sold Quantity', 'Average Price'); 
    $items = $this->itemRepository->getItem();
    foreach($items as $item) {
        $header_item[] = array(
            'Item Number'           => $item['item_number'],
            'Description'           => $item['description'],
            'Remaining Quantity'    => $item['remaining_quantity'],
            'Sold Quantity'         => $item['sold_quantity'],
            'Average Price'         => $item['average_price']
        );
    }
    Excel::create('Summary', function($excel) use ($header_item) {
        $excel->setTitle('Summary');
        $excel->sheet('Summary', function($sheet)
            use ($header_item) {
                $sheet->fromArray($header_item, null, 'A1', false, false);
            }
        );
    })->download('xlsx');
}
```

There exist error :

```
Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::create()
```

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

**Deprecations**

ALL Laravel Excel 2.* methods are deprecated and will not be able to use in 3.0 .

> Excel::create() is removed and replaced by
>   Excel::download/Excel::store($yourExport);

So either downgrade your version to `2.x` or use different methods according to the documentation.

See here: [To export / download](https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/docs/3.0/export/exportables)

[Upgrade Guide](https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/docs/3.0/getting-started/upgrade)

Comment: Can you provide a sample code for its application in my case? Actually I have tried it, but I am confused to set the title and save the array data

Comment: You can simply downgrade your Maatwebsite version to 2.x..Then your code works!

Comment: It can not. My project is using php version 7.1. So I must using laravel excel version 3

Comment: Did you try this https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/docs/3.0/export/exportables?

Comment: Then, what are you actually trying to do?